# Calculate delta time of specific column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I am working on these example below from a sensor data showing timestamp and status (either 0 or 1). I was able to calculate the delta of time between each row with same status, but I want to calculate the total length of time of each status (0 and 1).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['2018/02/16 15:00:05', 0],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:08', 0],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:09', 0],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:14', 1],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:26', 0],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:28', 0],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:29', 0],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:31', 1],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:33', 1],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:34', 1],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:37', 1],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:39', 1],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:40', 1],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:41', 1],
                        ['2018/02/16 15:00:43', 1]],
                  columns=['Datetime', 'Status'])

# convert to datetime object
df.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])

# find when the state changes
run_change = df['Status'].diff()

# get the step lengths
step_length = df['Datetime'].diff()

# loop and get the change since last state change
since_change = []
current_delta = 0
for is_change, delta in zip(run_change, step_length):
    current_delta = 0 if is_change != 0 else \
        current_delta + delta.total_seconds() 
    since_change.append(current_delta)

# add this data to the data frame
df['Run_Change'] = run_change
df['Step_Length'] = step_length
df['Time_Since_Change(sec)'] = pd.Series(since_change).values
```

and it turned out as:

```
Datetetime              Status      Run_Change  Step_Length Time_Since_Change
0   2018-02-16 15:00:05     0       NaN         NaT     0.0
1   2018-02-16 15:00:08     0       0.0     00:00:03    3.0
2   2018-02-16 15:00:09     0       0.0     00:00:01    4.0
3   2018-02-16 15:00:14     1       1.0     00:00:05    0.0 
4   2018-02-16 15:00:26     0      -1.0     00:00:12    0.0
5   2018-02-16 15:00:28     0       0.0     00:00:02    2.0
6   2018-02-16 15:00:29     0       0.0     00:00:01    3.0
7   2018-02-16 15:00:31     1       1.0     00:00:02    0.0
8   2018-02-16 15:00:33     1       0.0     00:00:02    2.0
9   2018-02-16 15:00:34     1       0.0     00:00:01    3.0
10  2018-02-16 15:00:37     1       0.0     00:00:03    6.0
```

I need the number of total length of time in seconds of whole data, for example, for status 0 the total length is 7 seconds (status 0 length is calculated from 00:05 to 00:09, continued 00:26 to 00:29).

Comment: Shouldn't be 24 seconds? (15:00:29 - 15:00:05)

Comment: So status 0 length is calculated from 00:05 to 00:09, continued 00:26 to 00:29

Comment: Okay, that would be useful to include it in the question.

Comment: Also (9-5)+(29-26)=7, not 10 (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `groupby('Status')` together with a `groupby(df2.index - np.arange(df2.shape[0]))`. This second `groupby` creates different series based on consecutive indices. Then you can just use a `groupby.last()` and `groupby.first()` to compute the time differences.

```
gb = df.groupby('Status')
t_list = []
for key, gp in gb:
    df2 = gb.get_group(key)
    gb2 = df2.groupby(df2.index - np.arange(df2.shape[0]))
    t_f = gb2.last()['Datetime'].values.astype('datetime64[s]')
    t_i = gb2.first()['Datetime'].values.astype('datetime64[s]')
    t = t_f-t_i
    t[np.where(t == np.timedelta64(0,'s'))] = np.timedelta64(1,'s')
    t_list.append(np.sum(t))

print(t_list) # [numpy.timedelta64(7,'s'), numpy.timedelta64(13,'s')]
```

Note the line

```
t[np.where(t == np.timedelta64(0,'s'))] = np.timedelta64(1,'s')
```

which substitutes a 0 second interval (a series with a single row since there is a single consecutive times) for 1 second (otherwise you would get 12 for Status 1 where it should be 13)